# onClick function not working in IE. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This code below works in every other browser bar IE. The code basically looks lets the uder pick a card, if it has, it chooses another card that hasn't been picked, and then adds it too an array. Unfortunately its not working in IE. No console errors.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

```
    function getCard(clicked_id)
{


$("#frontCard").animate({
    height:"-=600",
    width:"-=250",        
},1000,'easeOutElastic');
$("#frontCard").css("opacity",0);
clicked_id = "#" + clicked_id;


        $(clicked_id).animate({ opacity: 0, left: "700px" }, 'slow');

$("#frontCard").animate({
    height:"+=400",
    width:"+=250", 

},1000,'easeOutElastic');
$("#frontCard").css("opacity",1);
var newCard= Math.floor((Math.random()*13)+1);

var newSuit= Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var currentCard;
var x=document.getElementById("pick");
var rules=document.getElementById("rules");
var kings=document.getElementById("kings");
var currentCards=document.getElementById("currentCard");


if (cardsPicked.indexOf(numbers[newCard-1] + " " + suits[newSuit-1])== -1){

if (numbers[newCard-1]=="K" && king<4){
king=king+1;
}
if(king==4){
king= "All kings found!";
alert("Fourth king picked. Down the jug!");
}
cardsPicked.push(numbers[newCard-1] + " " + suits[newSuit-1] );
for (count=0; count<cardsPicked.length; count++)
currentRule = cardRules[newCard-1];

   x.innerHTML=cardsPicked;
   currentCards.innerHTML=numbers[newCard-1] + " " + suits[newSuit-1];
   rules.innerHTML=currentRule;
   kings.innerHTML=king;

}else{

getCard();
}
```

}

Comment: Whis Internet Version it is and in which mode it is?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    height:"-=600",
    width:"-=250",        
}

{
    height:"+=400",
    width:"+=250", 

}
```

Remove the trailing `,` in each of your comma separated values in Objects.

Comment: That didn't do anything. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the click event. But may be it helps:
Never overwrite the running event with innerHTML (in IE <10).